# PySpark Streaming example does not seem to terminate

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark

I am trying to understand the Python API of Spark Streaming by a simple example.

```
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
dvc = [[-0.1, -0.1], [0.1, 0.1], [1.1, 1.1], [0.9, 0.9]]
dvc = [sc.parallelize(i, 1) for i in dvc]
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2.0)
input_stream = ssc.queueStream(dvc)

def get_output(rdd):
    print(rdd.collect())
input_stream.foreachRDD(get_output)
ssc.start()
```

This prints the the required output, but then prints a lot of empty lists at the end and does not terminate. Can someone tell me where I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streaming in most cases(unless terminated by conditions in your code) is supposed to be infinite. The purpose of a streaming application is to consume data coming in at regular intervals. And hence after processing the first 4 RDDs `(i.e. [[-0.1, -0.1], [0.1, 0.1], [1.1, 1.1], [0.9, 0.9]])` you have nothing in the queue whereas spark streaming builds on the notion that something new might come into `queueStream`

If you are doing a one-time ETL you might consider dropping streaming.

Comment: I see, is there are a way to manually stop the Streaming application, say if x RDD's or n amount of data is received?

Comment: You can call `ssc.stop()`

Comment: I tried that, but it stops immediately without printing anything.

Comment: I meant something like this
`https://gist.github.com/hiteshd/388733ff10e4d428059c`

Comment: you can set timeout on your streaming job `self.streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout( timeout = self.run_time_minutes * 60 )` to run for some time and then stop.